# Is there an app for keyboard status

Tags: unity, keyboard, keyboard-layout

I have a brand new laptop, well it's only 3 weeks old, so nearly brand new. The only problem I find with it is that there is no visual display, light or sound, fitted to tell me whether the <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd> key is on or off. This is Packard Bell's way of why I didn't want to buy from them in the past!!!

Is there any software which would display the status of the <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd> key?

I have searched through the Software Centre for Caps Lock, keyboard status and installed KeyMon but it didn't work. I also asked Google to no avail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes you can do that.
open your terminal and paste these lines

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:tsbarnes/indicator-keylock
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install indicator-keylock
```

[image]

credit goes to [omgubuntu](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2010/09/indicator-keylock-ubuntu)

Comment: Perfect, just what the doctor ordered :)